# IIF Function returning incorrect calculated values - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a query to show returns of placing each way bets on horse races

There is an issue with the PlaceProfit result - This *should* show a return if the horses finishing position is between 1-4 and a loss if the position is => 5

It does show the correct return if the horses finishing position is below 9th, but 10th place and above is being counted as a win.

I include my code below along with the output.

```
ALTER VIEW EachWayBetting
AS
SELECT       a.ID,

RaceDate, 
runners, 
track.NAME AS Track, 
horse.NAME as HorseName, 
IndustrySP,
Place AS 'FinishingPosition',

-- // calculates returns on the win & place parts of an each way bet with 1/5 place terms //
IIF(A.Place = '1', 1.0 * (A.IndustrySP-1), '-1') AS WinProfit,
IIF(A.Place <='4', 1.0 * (A.IndustrySP-1)/5, '-1') AS PlaceProfit 

FROM         dbo.NewRaceResult a

     LEFT OUTER JOIN track ON track.ID = A.TrackID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN horse ON horse.ID = A.HorseID  
WHERE        a.Runners > 22
```

This returns:

[image: Query Results]

Comment: Looks like you;re storing `Place` as a string type data type, not a numerical data type. `'10'` has a ***lower*** value than `'4'`, and so is `Place` has a value of `'10'` then the expression `A.Place <= '4'` is **true**. Fix your design, store numerical data in a numerical data type (`int` seems appropriate here). `varchar` *isn't* a "one size fits all" data type; far from it.

Comment: Also, when using using literal numerical values, don't pass them as strings, for example `'-1'`. They should **not** be quoted (just `-1`).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, but the Place column may also store data such as 'PU' to indicate that the horse did not finish the race as it was 'Pulled Up' - do you know of a way around the issue I am having?

Comment: I would suggest, then, that you have 2 columns, one for the numerical place (which can be `NULL`) and a separate column to denote a failure for the horse to be classified, such as Pulled Up, Fell, etc. As it stands, it a 20 horse race, the top "3" horses would be those that finished in 1st, 10th and 11th, and the "last" horse would be the one that finished in 9th, not 20th,

Comment: Until you fix the data types you can apply `try_cast(place as int)` before calculation, this  changes from VarChar to Int and returns NULL for non-numeric strings like 'PU'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, the problem is your choice of data type for `place`, it's `varchar`. The ordering for a string data type is *completely* different to that of a numerical data type. Strings are sorted by character from left to right, in the order the characters are ordered in the collation you are using. Numerical data types, however, are ordered from the lowest to highest.

This means that, for a numerical data type, the value `2` has a **lower** value than `10`, however, for a `varchar` the value `'2'` has a **higher** value than `'10'`. For the `varchar` that's because the ordering is completed on the first character first. `'2'` has a higher value than `'1'` and so `'2'` has a higher value than `'10'`.

The solution here is simple, fix your design; store numerical data in a numerical data type (`int` seems appropriate here). You're also breaking Normal Form rules, as you're storing other data in the column; mainly the reason a horse failed to be classified. Such data isn't a "Place" but information on why the horse *didn't* place, and so should be in a separate column.

You can therefore fix this by firstly adding a new column, then updating it's value to be the values that aren't numerical and making `place` only contain numerical data, and then finally altering your `place` column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD UnClassifiedReason varchar(5) NULL; --Obviously use an appropriate length.
GO

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Place = TRY_CONVERT(int,Place),
    UnClassifiedReason = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,Place) IS NULL THEN Place END;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN Place int NULL;
GO
```

If `Place` does not allow `NULL` values, you will need to `ALTER` the column first to allow them.

Comment: Yes, separating the numeric and non numeric data was the solution here. I might add that when altering the column I had to drop the constraints first. I'd reference this answer on constraints since they describe giving them explicit names, which supports Gordon's advice below on meaningful naming conventions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48528902/12726001

Answer (score 2):

In addition to fixing the data as Larnu suggests, you should also fix the query:

```
SELECT nrr.ID, nrr.RaceDate, nrr.runners,
       t.NAME AS Track, t.NAME as HorseName, nrr.IndustrySP,
       Place AS FinishingPosition,
-- // calculates returns on the win & place parts of an each way bet with 1/5 place terms //
      (CASE WHEN nrr.Place = 1 THEN (nrr..IndustrySP - 1.0) ELSE -1 END) AS WinProfit,
      (CASE WHEN nrr.Place <= 4 THEN (nrr.IndustrySP - 1.0) / 5 THEN -1 END) AS PlaceProfit 
FROM dbo.NewRaceResult nrr LEFT JOIN
     track t
     ON t.ID = nrr.TrackID LEFT JOIN
     horse h
     ON h.ID = nrr.HorseID  
WHERE nrr.Runners > 22;
```

The important changes are removing single quotes from numbers and column names.  It seems you need to understand the differences among strings, numbers, and identifiers.

Other changes are:

- Meaningful table aliases, rather than meaningless letters such as `a`.
- Qualifying *all* column references, so it is clear where columns are coming from.
- Switching from `IFF()` to `CASE`.  `IFF()` is bespoke SQL Server; `CASE` is standard SQL for conditional expressions (both work fine).
- Being sure that the types returned by all branches of the conditional expressions are consistent.

Note:  This version will work even if you don't change the type of `Place`.  The strings will be converted to numbers in the appropriate places.  I don't advocate relying on such silent conversion, so I recommend fixing the data.

If `place` can have non-numeric values, then you need to convert them:

```
      (CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, nrr.Place) = 1 THEN (nrr..IndustrySP - 1.0) ELSE -1 END) AS WinProfit,
      (CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, nrr.Place) <= 4 THEN (nrr.IndustrySP - 1.0) / 5 THEN -1 END) AS PlaceProfit
```

But the important point is to fix the data.

Comment: **"This version will work even if you don't change the type of Place."* Unfortunately the OP is actually storing non-numerical data in `Place` as well, so you either need to remove that from the data, or eliminate it from the data first before the `CASE` expression is executed.

Comment: @Larnu . . . How do you know that?  I don't see any indication in the question that there are non-numeric values.

Comment: From the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087023/problem-using-the-iif-function-how-to-calculate-each-way-bets-sql-server/64088720?noredirect=1#comment113326846_64087023) and the image (which shows one row has the value `'PU'`).