# Change data type of atribute in SQL , int convert to date

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do this below :

```
alter table employee 
alter column em_year date
```

But I encounted issue:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 55
> The object 'DF_em_year' is dependent on column 'em_year'.
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 55
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN em_year failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: You need to drop and recreate the `DEFAULT` constraint.

Comment: Please perform some research of your problem before posting in accordance with [ask]. Duplicate of [ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because one or more objects access this column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549413/alter-table-drop-column-failed-because-one-or-more-objects-access-this-column)